# Differences between Dictionary.Clear and new Dictionary()

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

What are the key differences between `Dictionary.Clear` and `new Dictionary()` in C#? Which one is recommended for which cases?

Comment: performance related: [which-is-faster-clear-collection-or-instantiate-new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901020/which-is-faster-clear-collection-or-instantiate-new)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`Dictionary.Clear()` will remove all of the `KeyValue` pairs within the dictionary.  Doing `new Dictionary()` will create a new instance of the dictionary.

If, and only if, the old version of the dictionary is not rooted by another reference, creating a new dictionary will make the entire dictionary, and it's contents (which are not rooted elsewhere) available for cleanup by the GC.

`Dictionary.Clear()` will make the `KeyValue` pairs available for cleanup.

In practice, both options will tend to have very similar effects.  The difference will be what happens when this is used within a method:

```
void NewDictionary(Dictionary<string,int> dict)
{
   dict = new Dictionary<string,int>(); // Just changes the local reference
}

void  ClearDictionary(Dictionary<string,int> dict)
{
   dict.Clear();
}

// When you use this...
Dictionary<string,int> myDictionary = ...; // Set up and fill dictionary

NewDictionary(myDictionary);
// myDictionary is unchanged here, since we made a new copy, but didn't change the original instance

ClearDictionary(myDictionary);
// myDictionary is now empty
```

Comment: @divo - I think he means a copy of the reference, not a copy of the object itself

Comment: @John: That was exactly what I meant.  It is a copy - a copy of the reference to the dictionary

Comment: If the dictionary is passed into a method where it is set to a new instance and elements are added, then an out modifier needs to be added to the parameter argument, otherwise the returned variable will not have the elements.  An out parameter creates further issues by requiring the dictionary to be instantiated in all control branches (if/switch) within the method, which will remove existing elements.  So if you need to pass a dictionary to a method that sometimes removes all elements and return added elements, then Dictionary.Clear() is best.

Comment: _Dictionary.Clear() will make the KeyValue pairs available for cleanup._ Which 'KeyValue pairs' are you referring to? The .NET Framework dictionary implementation does not use `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair` for storing data internally: [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs).

Answer (score 24):

As has been extensively covered, the effects are essentially the same.  `Clear()` and `new` would both give you a fresh Dictionary, essentially abandoning the references to the objects inside of it, freeing them to be collected if they became unrooted.

Technically, `.Clear()` would have an advantage over `new` if you were about to repopulate the dictionary to the same size as it was before.  This is because it would have been already resized internally to hold the number of objects that you had in it before.  Creating a new Dictionary would have a new internal hashtable with the default size, and it would have to be re-expanded as you added items to it.

I would also suggest that they communicate a completely different intent, and you should use `.Clear()` in your code when you're dealing with the same context as before.  Creating a new Dictionary implies that you are about to embark on some new logic dealing with something different than the old Dictionary, while using `Clear()` indicates that yes, you really wanted to just reset everything you've done so far with it.

Comment: > Creating a new Dictionary would have a new internal hashtable with the default size - not necessarily, you can use a constructor overload to set the initial capacity.

Comment: Yep.  I was assuming just a .Clear() vs. a new Dictionary().

Answer (score 13):

**Dictionary.Clear()**
This will remove all key/value pairs within the Dictionary.   The Garbage Collector will clear the memory for these items during the next Garbage Collection Cycle.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5txwy7s(VS.85).aspx)

**new Dictionary()**
Creates a new Dictionary object in memory and abandons the original object. The memory would be cleared during the next Garbage Collection Cycle.

Comment: That MSDN article doesn't say anything about disposing.

Comment: Something to consider - if your dictionary is very large, and you're sure that you'll be loading about the same about of data after the clear - the fact that Dictionary.Clear() doesn't reset the dictionary's capacity will make it more attractive.

Comment: @overslacked - Damn I just spent time writing an answer that suggested exactly that.

Comment: You forget that other references aren't "cleared" when you allocate a new Dictionary... I would almost downvote for missing this.

Comment: @Dykam, assuming entries aren't rooted elsewhere (which I think is safe to assume if you're deciding between clear/new), mentioning that the original object is abandoned seems enough of a warning.
@womp, upvoted! I haven't profiled the effect, and I don't know that it's as much a concern now as it used to be, so I simply hitched my wagon to the leader :)

Comment: _The Garbage Collector will clear the memory for these items during the next Garbage Collection Cycle_ that's not really meaningful or accurate. There could exist other references to the contents of the dictionary keeping them alive, for example.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose the key difference is that if you call `Dictionary.Clear()`, all references to that dictionary will be cleared. If you use `new Dictionary()`, then the reference you are dealing with at the time will be cleared (in a sense), but all other places you have references won't be since they will still be referring to the old dictionary.

Hopefully this code illustrates it simply:

```
public void Method()
{
    Dictionary<int, int> d1 = new Dictionary();

    d1.Add(1,1);
    d1.Add(2,3);

    Dictionary<int, int> d2 = d1;

    //this line only 'clears' d1
    d1 = new Dictionary();

    d1.Add(1,1);
    d1.Add(3,5);
    d2.Add(2,2);

    //writes '2' followed by '1'
    Console.WriteLine(d1.Count);
    Console.WriteLine(d2.Count);
}
```

If I had called `d1.Clear()` instead, then d1 and d2 would have remained in sync, and the subsequent adds would have added to both. The WriteLine calls would both have output '3' instead.

Answer (score 4):

`Dictionary.Clear` will remove (but not dispose) all items in the instance whereas `new Dictionary()` will create a brand new instance which just happens to be empty.  There may be some subtle implications between the two.  Consider the following examples.

```
void Example1()
{
  var collection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  collection.Add("key1", "value1");
  collection.Add("key2", "value2");
  foreach (var kvp in collection)
  {
    collection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Console.WriteLine(kvp);
  }
}

void Example2()
{
  var collection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  collection.Add("key1", "value1");
  collection.Add("key2", "value2");
  foreach (var kvp in collection)
  {
    collection.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine(kvp);
  }
}
```

In the first example all of the contents from the original collection will be printed.  That is because the enumerator was created from the reference variable before it was reassigned to a new instance.

In the second example the collection is cleared during an enumeration which will result in an `InvalidOperationException` because the collection was modified.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that .Clear() was provided so that if your Dictionary is exposed as a read-only property you would be able to remove all of the items.  However, if it's not exposed that way, and you have complete control then it might be easier to just instantiate a new Dictionary.  There might be a slight performance difference between the two, also.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary.Clear()` ([source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,216)) resets the dictionary's internal data structures. The [`Entry`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,61) structs used internally will be eligible for garbage collection, as will any keys and values which were reachable only via those entries. The capacity of the dictionary, which may have grown since it was instantiated, remains the same.

`new Dictionary()` allocates a new object. The initial capacity of the new dictionary will be either the default or the value you specified, depending on which [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8.1) you used. This may differ from the capacity of the existing dictionary had you used the `Clear()` approach. Whether this is significant will depend on your circumstances.

`Dictionary.Clear()` provides a way to empty a dictionary where other references exist to the object which you cannot update to point to a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several references to that dictionary and you clear it you will affect them all where as if you create a new dictionary you will only affect the one new reference.  I guess it depends on the scope of the impact that you're aiming for.  Obviously a call to "new" will give you a "cleared" dictionary but you might lose other useful state information.

Answer (score -1):

Dictionary.clear will evict all of the items in your dictionary. new Dictionary creates a new dictionary object in memory while orphaning your previous Dictionary for the garbage collector to clean up later.

Comment: Can we do better than "most likely"? That's going to be a key question here.

Comment: I don't think that the dictionary will ever call Dispose on items which it contains; if the items are disposable I think you should write explicit code to dispose them.

Comment: Why would it call dispose on anything?  Just because they're in a dictionary doesn't mean they're not in use elsewhere.  That would be horribly buggy.  All it does is null the hashtable buckets.