# Is it bad form to let C# garbage collect a list instead of reusing it?

Tags: c#, list, garbage-collection

I have a list of elements that steadily grows, until I dump all the data from that list into a file. I then want to reuse that list for the same purpose again. Is it bad practice to simply assign it to a new list, instead of removing all the elements from the list? It seems garbage collection should take care of the old list, and that way I don't have to worry about removing the elements.

For example:

```
var myList = new List<element>();
myList.Add(someElement);
myList.Add(anotherElement);
// dumps the elements into a file

myList = new List<element>();
```

Edit: Even if there are easy ways around this, I was wondering too about the philosophical side of it. Is it bad to let something be garbage collected if there is a way around it? What are the costs of allowing garbage collection vs deleting the elements and reusing the same memory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106537/using-the-clear-method-vs-new-object

Comment: See my edited answer for comments on your edit.

Comment: I bet you won't see any difference when you measure it. But one thing: When you create a new `List<>` that is going to be long, if you know approximately how long it is going to become, it is an optimization to use `new List<element>(capacity)` where `capacity` is an `int`. This is useful whether you instantiate `List<>` only once, or does it many times (re-assigning).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends a bit on how many elements are in the list.  If the array backing the list is large enough to be on the large object heap, then you might be better off clearing the list and reusing it.  This will reduce the number of large memory allocations, and will help reduce the problem of large object heap fragmentation.  (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx and http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-dangers-of-the-large-object-heap/ for more information; see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/10/04/large-object-heap-improvements-in-net-4-5.aspx for improvements due with .NET 4.5)

If the lists are small, you might be better off just creating a new list, or you might get better performance calling `Clear()`.  When in doubt, measure the performance.

Edit: In response to the philosophical question you pose in your edit, here are two reasons to create a new list:

1. In general, code is cleaner and easier to reason about if you do not reuse objects.  The cost of garbage collection is low, the cost of confusing code is high.
2. Consider what happens if the code dumping the list's contents is in another function, as it most likely is.  Once you've passed that list out of its local context, it's possible that there are non-local references to the same list.  Other code might be modifying the list, or might be assuming (incorrectly) that you're not modifying it.

Answer (score 6):

`myList.Clear()` is even easier to code than `myList = new List<element>();`

[msdn: List.Clear Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Each element in the list is a different object itself, and will need to be garbage collected whether you clear the list, or recreate a new list, or remove the items one at a time.  What will NOT need to be garbage collected if you just clear the list and reuse it is the list itself.  Unless your list is huge, containing hundreds of thousands of items, it will be difficult to measure a performance difference one way or the other.  Fortunately, the garbage collector is highly optimized and it's a rare occurrence where developers need to consider what it is doing.

(As others have pointed out, there are various factors involved, such as...how many elements will you be adding to the new list? vs how many elements were in the old list? ...but the point is: the garbage collection of the list itself isn't relevant when it comes to collecting the elements of the list.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but:
Making a *new* list expecting that the GC will "take care" of the old one is probably a *bad* idea because it's a bad practice & probably inefficient.
Although it's a micro-optimization, I'd say that "setting" the new values until you reach `list.Count`, and the continuing to `list.Add` is the best way, because then you don't clear nor allocate unnecessary new memory (unless it's large lists which you **want** to clear for space)
Anyway, I would recommend using `List.Clear()` - it saves you and the GC trouble.

Comment: It seems like you're saying "it's a bad idea because it's a bad idea"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking two different questions. One is whether it's okay to set it to a new object or just clear it, which I think Eric answered pretty well. The second is whether you should just ignore the GC and let it work without trying to "help" it - to that, I'd say absolutely YES. Let the framework do what the framework does and stay out of its way until you have to.

A lot of programmers want to dig in too deep, and most of the time it causes more problems than it helps. The GC is designed to collect these things and clean them up for you. Unless you are seeing a very specific problem, you should write the code that works and pay ignore when something will be collected (with the exception of the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) keyword when appropriate).

Comment: This answer might not be relevant anymore. The framework has proven itself to be slow. And programs need to be fast, some programs need to be even faster. I think the notion of let the framework do its' job... is dead. Now we have span and inline arrays, and stack objects and fixed objects. So many concepts now that fight against the GC, or at least, try to educate it. No, don't just let the GC do it's job. A single GC stutter is a big F.

Answer (score 0):

The important perspective is clean code.
when you create a new list the old one will be removed by the GC (if there are no other reference to it.)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather to use `List.Clear()` to remove all the elements for re-use. The Capacity remain unchanged so there shouldn't have additional overhead cost and letting GC to handle the memory garbage collection so you can maintain clean code.